# Flaging selected dates if they fall within existing dates in an sql table using Visual Basic .Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

Edited:
i have this date range: `2020-03-12 to 2020-03-13`

and then i have the sql table below:

```
RoomNumber ResStartDate ResEndDate
101        2020-02-17   2020-02-22
101        2020-02-14   2020-03-22
101        2020-03-11   2020-03-14
101        2020-04-11   2020-04-14
```

i want to insert this date range `2020-03-12 to 2020-03-13` into the table only if there are no overlapping days with any of the date ranges in the table.

Comment: I think we need more information about that. To be more clear I mean you must add in your question details such as how you get this data (dates) from db, how you want to be this comparison (via SQL, or in VB.NET code etc).
Without a piece of code which show us how you are working over this, for us is a little difficult to help you.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj I am currently using the three table fields(RoomNumber, ResStartDate,ResEndDate) as a primary key. However, this only works if the selected dates are exactly the same to the dates in the table, it does not consider overlapping dates. I want the comparison via SQL.

Comment: why are u not just using > and < operators to check your startDate and EndDate from datepicker? or colour the datepicker values (ex. red) so you can inform user, which dates are occupied

Comment: @Peter Ksenak I tried that but how do I check against all the dates in the table? that solution would work if I was checking against particular dates and not all dates.

Comment: just loop through each row

Comment: @Peter Ksenak that is what i dunno how to do

Comment: @PeterKsenak This question is tagged vb.net not vba.

Comment: @Samuel Ronald -   Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader() and then  While reader.Read() End While

Comment: @Peter Ksenak I have edited the question maybe it will give a clear picture of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In supplement to Gordon's answer, here's his query in some VB:

```
Dim tableName as String = YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE

Dim sql as String = "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " (roomNumber, resStartDate, resEndDate)
    SELECT roomNumber, resStartDate, resEndDate
    FROM (VALUES (@rn, @st, @ed)) v(roomNumber, resStartDate, resEndDate)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM " + tablename + " t WHERE t.roomNumber = v.roomNumber AND t.resEndDate > v.resStartDate AND t.resStartDate < v.resEndDate)"

Dim sqlCommand as New SqlCommand(sql, YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_HERE)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rn", YOUR_ROOM_NUMBER_VARIABLE_HERE)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", YOUR_START_DATE_VARIABLE_HERE)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", YOUR_END_DATE_VARIABLE_HERE)

Dim ins as Integer = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

If ins = 0 Then
  MessageBox.Show("Those dates overlap with another reservation")
Else
  MessageBox.Show("Room is reserved")
End If
```

You need to replace the `YOUR_xxxx` words with actual values

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the number of overlaps with this logic:

```
select count(*)
from t
where roomNumber = 101 and
      resEndDate > '2020-03-12' and
      resStartDate < '2020-03-13';
```

The logic is simple.  Two timeframe overlap if the first starts before the second ends and the first ends after the first starts.  This covers all cases of overlap (although you might want `<=` and `>=` if the end points count as overlaps).

You can put this into an insert:

```
insert into t (roomNumber, resStartDate, resEndDate)
    select roomNumber, resStartDate, resEndDate
    from (values (101, '2020-03-12', '2020-03-13')
         ) v(roomNumber, resStartDate, resEndDate)
    where not exists (select 1
                      from t
                      where t.roomNumber = v.roomNumber and
                            t.resEndDate > v.resStartDate and
                            t.resStartDate < v.resEndDate
                     );
```

Comment: Additional advice: If put to an insert, one should examine the integer return value of the client side call `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` to see whether the record was inserted or not. A return of 1 indicates an insert, 0 means no insert

Comment: I have tried his solution but it still inserts the two dates yet they overlap some dates in the table.

Comment: @SamuelRonald . . . You would need to provide sample data (in your question, preferably in a db<>fiddle).  This logic should work as written.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I provided sample data in the original post

Comment: @SamuelRonald . . . You did not provide it in a usable format.  An image is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems relatively simple. You can know this before you go saving with a simple query like: ***(NOTE: to be considered only as demonstrative way to do your stuff)***

```
SELECT       COUNT(*) AS RecCount
FROM         Reservations 
WHERE        RoomNumber = 101
AND          (ResStartDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-02-20 12:30:00', 102)  AND  ResStartDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-02-25 18:30:00', 102))
 OR          (ResEndDate   >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-02-20 12:30:00', 102)  AND  ResEndDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-02-25 18:30:00', 102))
```

If this query have records, means you had had a reservation before, in those dates.
I’m using SQL SERVER in this query but you can use your DB approach as well.
Note that: `'2020-02-20'` is value of datepicker1 AND  `'2020-02-25'` is value of datepicker1 
In your question is not talked for hours but I think is important also to knows hours.

Comment: How do I check the value returned by RecCount?

Comment: Not sure this logic is correct. It only checks whether one time frame in the table is wholly within the (Feb 20 to Feb 25) time frame in the constants? What if the table time frame is outwith? Perhaps you meant `WHERE room AND (start between feb20 to feb25` **OR** `end between feb20 to feb25)` ?

Comment: @Caius Jard this is what I can achieve at the moment, before I asked the question I could achieve that however, i want the two dates checked against all the other dates in the table for overlaps

Comment: Yes folks yes. As I was in "quickly" mode that was a mistake. Need to be OR